# How to loop over an array in Smarty/Prestashop?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty

I use this code in Prestashop

```
{if (strpos($product.name, 'TVNUMBER1') !== false)}
    THIS PRODUCT IS IN SALE
{/if}
```

So whenever I want to display that certain products are in sale, I have to go line by line, specifying the same product i.e."TVNUMBER1". **I want to be able to write an array** detailing all the products I have in sale "TV1, TV2, TV3", and get a code like this:

```
{if (strpos($product.name, '$array') !== false)}
    THIS PRODUCT IS IN SALE
{/if}
```

I've tried similar examples found here, but I can't get them to work, either in Prestashop or in PHP testers online. It looks super simple, but I can't get around it.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Did you try a for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the `in_array` php function, that check if a given $needle is or not in an array.

So what you should do is :

```
{if (in_array($product.name, '$array') !== false)}
    THIS PRODUCT IS IN SALE
{/if}
```

Then in your controller you can assign the array to smarty :

```
$arr = array('TVNUMBER1', 'TVNUMBER2', 'TVNUMBER3');
$smarty->assign('myArray', $arr);
```

Comment: Perfect, I used this and it worked perfectly. I didn't use the controller part cos I don't know how to get it working, but I used the rest, and inserted the `$arr = array('TVNUMBER1', 'TVNUMBER2', 'TVNUMBER3');` inside the .tpl

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Smarty as template engine. So you could do something like this (from [the doc](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)).

In the controller

```
//Give it to the view
$arr = array('TVNUMBER1', 'TVNUMBER2');
$smarty->assign('myArray', $arr);
```

And in the view

```
//In the view, loop over the array
{foreach from=$myArray item=productName}
    //If your product is among the in-sale ones, show the message
    {if (strpos($product.name, productName) !== false)}
        THIS PRODUCT IS IN SALE
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, I'm sure that works fine. I've tried it, but I honestly don't know how to implement that first part. Thanks, I will keep on reading the Smarty manuals.

Comment: You can fetch all the products from your database, Prestashop probably already a global object to fetch from the database.